# Open Source Shopping Cart for selling game cd key

Tags: shopping-cart, bitcoin

I'm looking for an open Source Shopping Cart like Opencart but specific for selling game cd key which no registration require for buyers. I just need their email address then will automatically send cd key after they pay. Payment gateway supports Bitcoin, Altcoin and Paypal. Any recommendation ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Payments with cybercurrency and open source shopping carts, is not something you will find.
You can extend for example OpenCart by adding the functionality of sending the cd key by email after order completion.

Guest checkout is already supported by OpenCart, also Paypal payments.